# Why does Java RMI not need a skeleton?

Tags: java, rmi

I am new to RMI and am more familiar with basic RPC. In RMI what takes care of the demarshalling of parameters, passing them to relevant procedures etc. on the server side if not the skeleton? As far as I'm aware, skeletons were present in the early RMI versions but then got deprecated.

Comment: Because they changed the protocol in 1998 so as not to need a *generated* skeleton, to use Reflection instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! If you say they don't need a 'generated' skeleton, I feel as if you're implying there is some type of skeleton ins

Comment: They now use a dynamic proxy as the skeleton.